# How to copy values from a list that do not contain specific characters?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy

I would like to copy specific values from a list of values as long as the cell doesn't contain a specific text substring, for example;

```
A                           B
texta                       texta   
textd                       textd   
text1                       texta
text1.2                     textb
text1.3                     textc
text1.2                     text2
texta       would become:   textb           
textb                       text2.1
textc                       
text1.3                     
text1.2                     
text2                       
textb                       
text2.1
```

Is there a forumla that could copy a cell as long as it doesn't contain specific text string & blank values?

Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention these formulas that I have tried to use;                                       =IF('sheet1'!A1<>"*text1*", 'sheet1'!A1, 'sheet1'!A2)                                                            &                                                                                                                                              =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"*text1*","*text1.2*","*text1.3*"},'sheet1'!A1)),'sheet1'!A2,'sheet1'!A1)

Comment: I would use vba and Instr to check if substring present

Comment: In your example, what is the specific text sub-string you are checking for??

Comment: In my example it's any value which contains the text sub-string "text1" that needs to be ignored / not added to the new list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Instr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function) to test if string is present. Hold qualifying results (where not present) in an [`ArrayList`](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arraylist_en.html) and write that list out at the end:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetValuesWithoutSubString()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, list As Object
    Const TEST_STRING As String = "text1"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
        Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            With list
                If Not InStr(arr(i, 1), TEST_STRING) > 0 and arr(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
                    .Add arr(i, 1)
                End If
            End With
        Next i
        .Range("B1").Resize(list.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(list.ToArray)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Multiple exclusions:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetValuesWithoutSubString()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, list As Object
    Dim exclusions(), found As Boolean, j As Long
    exclusions = Array("text1", "texta")
    'text1" and "texta

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
        Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            found = False
            With list
                For j = LBound(exclusions) To UBound(exclusions)
                    If InStr(arr(i, 1), exclusions(j)) > 0 Then
                       found = True
                       Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If Not found Then .Add arr(i, 1)
            End With
        Next i
        .Range("B1").Resize(list.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(list.ToArray)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is amazing thanks so much!  I'm not too familiar with macros yet but this code is really elegant & I was able to easily identify which references would need to be altered in order to work correctly with my data.  Apologies if I'm being cheeky but is it possible to add a search for "(blank)" so that value is also ignored?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough, I meant as in is it possible to add in one or more text-string(s) to the macro e.g. search & ignore "text1" and "texta"?  I used "(blank)" as an example in my previous comment because some of the values are literally the string "(blank)".

Comment: That's great, I was thinking of running multiple macros that have been slightly amended but the number needed would probably be in the dozens if not hundreds

Comment: Works perfectly, can't thank you enough!  I really need to learn vba, seems so cool

Answer (score 1):

If your values are in column A and the values two be excluded are in column C then in column B you can put this array formula and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

> =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$14, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$14,$C$1:$C$3,0)), "",
>   ROW($A$1:$A$14)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$14))+1), ROW(A1))),"")

[image]